# Why is it the empty element of a List are not replaced with default value in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have the below Scala Code

**Code:**

```
object ReplaceNulls {

  def main(args:Array[String]) = {
    val myList = List("surender", "", null)

    val myUpdatedList = myList.map {
      case a: String => a
      case null => "OTHERS"
      case "" => "OTHERS"
    }

    println(myUpdatedList)
}
```

This above Code gives me the below Output

```
List(surender, , OTHERS)
```

But the expected output is below

```
List(surender,OTHERS,OTHERS)
```

What went wrong in my code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because "" is also of type string and will match the first case i.e `case a:String`. You can try changing the order of case statements

```
object ReplaceNulls {

def main(args:Array[String])={

val myList = List("surender","",null)

val myUpdatedList = myList.map { x => x match{
                                               case ""  =>"OTHERS" 
                                               case a:String => a
                                               case null => "OTHERS" 

                                               } 
}

println(myUpdatedList)

 }

}
```

Comment: Ahh, Yes, Thanks Much !

Comment: I am waiting to accept this answer as the system does not allow me to do that.. It seems we can submit our acceptance only  after some (0-10)mins